# How to keep UIView center using UIScrollview contentoffset iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview

I have `UIView` inside of `UIScrollView` which contains 4 subviews. while  tapping on subview i want to adjust scrollview's `contentoffset` property in such way that my tapped `subview` is align to center of screen.

I tried some logic but it not working properly.

```c
-(void)onDragViewTapped:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)recognizer
{
    CGFloat width = self.scrollVw.contentSize.width/2;
    CGFloat vwWidth = recognizer.view.frame.size.width/2;
    width = width - vwWidth - vwWidth/self.scrollVw.zoomScale - 
    width/self.scrollVw.zoomScale;

    CGFloat height = self.scrollVw.contentSize.height/2;
    CGFloat vwHeigh = recognizer.view.frame.size.height/2;
    height = height- vwHeigh -  vwHeigh/self.scrollVw.zoomScale - 
    height/self.scrollVw.zoomScale;

    [self.scrollVw setContentOffset:CGPointMake(width, height) 
    animated:YES];
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works for me (without zooming actually):

```
// This view below here is the view of the view controller, 
// use the container view instead to align the center to
let newX = tappedView.center.x - view.center.x
let newY = tappedView.center.y - view.center.y
scrollview.setContentOffset(CGPoint(x: newX, y: newY), animated: true)
```

Comment: Yes Its working perfectly without zooming. but how we upgrade this with zooming that is with zooming scale?

Answer (score 0):

**As per Apple documents,Converting Between View Coordinate Systems**

Converts a point from the receiver’s coordinate system to that of the specifie view.

- **func convert(CGPoint, to: UIView?) -> CGPoint**

Converts a point from the coordinate system of a given view to that of the receiver.

- **func convert(CGPoint, from: UIView?) -> CGPoint**

Converts a rectangle from the receiver’s coordinate system to that    of another
   view.

- **func convert(CGRect, to: UIView?) -> CGRect**

Converts a rectangle from the coordinate system of another view to that of the receiver.

- **func convert(CGRect, from: UIView?) -> CGRect**

I think this will help you.